# How to override all css style classes in an input field without effecting other elements?

Tags: css

I am customizing an input field to be 100% witdh. I am confused if I have to do this:

**First:**

```
.fullwidth
input,
input[type="text"]
 {
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing : border-box;‌​
    -moz-box-sizing : border-box;
    box-sizing : border-box;
    height: 35px;
}
```

or just

**Second:**

```
.fullwidth
 {
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing : border-box;‌​
    -moz-box-sizing : border-box;
    box-sizing : border-box;
    height: 35px;
}
```

Somehow the second one is not giving any effect to my textbox. But when I used the first one, it affects all input field in the document, ruining other elements' styles.

Comment: You can give an input an ID..

Comment: You should provide class for input element and apply style for that class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should give an id to your input

```
<input type="text" id="yourId" name="yourName">
```

And in your css file you should write

```
#yourId
{
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing : border-box;‌​
    -moz-box-sizing : border-box;
    box-sizing : border-box;
    height: 35px;
}
```

It should work

Comment: Thanks sir! it did work. But can you please explain why the second css class I wrote did not work like the one using the ID? Logically they are the same, just the class can be used multiple times but the one with ID is not

Comment: Maybe there was, no class assigned to your input as `<input class=".fullwidth" type="text" name="yourName">`. `.fullwidth` will apply to every element with fullwidth as class.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps in your file, there is an element called `.fullwidth` wrapping the `input`

### HTML:

```
<div class="fullwidth">
    <input type="text">
</div>
```

### Your problem:

Because `.fullwidth input` direct the style to the input and `.fullwidth` only applies to the parent element but the input, which still has its default width. **Only the first one would work**. **However**, you typed `, input[type="text"] {` in your first condition, which means: **All input element in a .fullwidth class AND all input element with the attribute type set to "text" will apply the following style**

Remember, browsers set different styles default to different element, while the common `div` is given a default `width:100%;`. A input is given `width:SOMEPIXELS;`

### Solution:

```
.fullwidth input[type="text"],
 {
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing : border-box;‌​
    -moz-box-sizing : border-box;
    box-sizing : border-box;
    height: 35px;
}
```

This solution states **All children input element with the attribute type set to "text" under a .fullwidth class will apply the following style**

Answer (score 0):

**Try to be more specific in your selector**

I doubt whether the input has class `fullwidth`.

As per your second solution, you are giving styles to the `fullwidth` class while in first solution you are giving styles to `input` inside `fullwidth`.

If your input has class fullwidth then try `input.fullwidth`.

If that doesn't work then refer your input using it's parent class i.e. `parent-class input.fullwidth` .

If still that doesn't work, you can add another class for width, left say `temp` and then you can refer it using `input.fullwidth.temp`